# How to work with Master Page that is attached to the page via the page's basepage?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, master-pages, designer, onpreinit

In my ASP.Net web application, I have a base page that implements functionality that spans all pages of the web application and my web pages derive from this base page.

Since there is a single master page for the entire website, I don't want to attach the master page in each of the web pages. So I attached the Master page via the basepage's OnPreInit method as follows:

```
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = "~/Site.master";
        base.OnPreInit(e);
    }
```

However, when I switch to Designer view, I get the "Master Page Error"; The page has controls that require a Master Page reference, but noe is specified. Correct the problem in Code View.
[image]

When I run the application, the webpage shows up correctly.

What should be done so that the designer shows up correctly without having to go and set the master page explicitly in each of the web pages?

BTW, I am on Visual Studio 2010 and .Net 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in luck you can set the masterpage file in your **web.config**, and it will show in the designer without being explicitly set on the page.  I just tested it out.  Just look for the line below and put in your master page file.

```
<pages masterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master">
```

Comment: To add onto this answer - if you are setting something like a MasterPage in the code behind, you won't see it in the designer.  The aspx page and the code behind are two separate files.  Except for setting application-wide rules in the config file, you're out of luck getting a visual in the design view unless explicitly setting the MasterPage, for example, on the page or in the web.config.

Comment: If you've already tested that your logic to programmatically set the MasterPage is working correctly, set the MasterPage in the files you're working on.  P.S. - The design view is terrible for working on styling.:)

Comment: Agreed the design view is not all that great once your masterpages and stuff become more complex.  I do use it occasionally to drag in controls or generate event handler code, but after that I usually move it around to where I want in the source view.