# Blog Engine 2.0 Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, c#-4.0, blogengine.net

I AM getting an error while opening blogengine.net 2.0 in visual studio 2010 designer view.It is showing the master page error.

But while executing the page it is loading correctly.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4080393/19090).

This has to do with the fact that BlogEngine.net is setting the Master Page in the PreInit event of the page's base class ([BlogBasePage](http://blogengine.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/34cfa6667067#BlogEngine%2fDotNetSlave.BusinessLogic%2fWeb%2fControls%2fBlogBasePage.cs)). It does this based on the theme you have chosen. Because of that, at design time VS can't figure out what the master page is.

You could set a default master page file in the web.config `<pages>` directive, as in the answer to the question above. The master page file you use would be based on the theme you are using (/themes/yourtheme/site.master).

Comment: thank you patmortech.I made the changes in webconfig.i am able to view the pages correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the master page is determined dynamically?

Try opening in code (rather than designer) and seeing what the `MasterPageFile` attribute of the `@Page` directive says.

Comment: thank You.the masterpagefile attribute was missing in the pages.